# Using input type file with Resend

Tags: javascript, file, email, resend.com

I'm using a simple contact `<form>` to send emails to a given address, it works fine, now i need to add file attachments, i have an `input` of `type="file"`, and it can take in multiple files

How do i go from that to a `string`/`buffer` format like it says in the docs ?

https://resend.com/docs/api-reference/emails/send-email

Example :

```
await resend.emails.send({
  from: 'Acme <onboarding@resend.dev>',
  to: ['delivered@resend.dev'],
  subject: 'hello world',
  text: 'it works!',
  attachments: [
    {
      filename: 'invoice.pdf',
      content: invoiceBuffer,
    },
  ]
});
```

The format i use, either a string or a buffer, must be includable in the POST request's body, since what i do now is a `JSON.stringify(data)` of my `<form>` data and send it to the backend so it does the email sending.

I tried finding a solution with chat GPT, it suggests using `FormData`, which is fine, but it never gets the format right, either it's broken when sent ( an empty array, instead of a file as string ), or it goes through but then i get the **content must be in string or buffer format"** error.

I'm really stuck, any help is appreciated .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found answer here : https://github.com/resend/resend-examples/blob/main/with-attachments-content/src/pages/index.tsx

the trick is to use this to read the file as a string :

```
  const onAddFileAction = (e) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    const files = e.target.files;

    reader.onload = (r) => {
      setContent(r.target.result.toString());
      setFilename(files[0].name);
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
  };
```

And then make the handler for your `<input type="file" onChange={onAddFileAction}/>`

And then use fetch to call the API :

```
  await fetch('/api/send', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      content: base64Content,
      filename,
    }),
  });
```